# Handling aborted http requests Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

I've been reeding an article https://www.meziantou.net/handling-aborted-requests-in-asp-net-core.htm and I wonder is there any functionality to handle client aborted requests in Rails.
I've been always thinking that it's not possible to handle such situations. Maybe some has any thoughts about this.

**Problem**
We have legacy project and some http requests are very heavy and performed not async. That means that client can wait for some time and then close tab or reload page. But this heavy request is stilled performed on server side (Ruby on Rails)

**My idea**
From the client we can generate uniq X-Request-ID and fill it in request headers. Then on server side we can keep this id in Redis and set `updated_at=Time.now`. If rails app finishes request => delete X-Request-ID from Redis. After that from the client we can send polling requests to update time for this uniq id. With Sidekiq worker we can grab all ids that are not updated any more. Is it possible to stop server from performing request by X-Request-ID ?

**P.S.** I know it sounds like it's better to use web-sockets where we can handle connection abort but I need to do it for http requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can think in using this feature JS to alert client not reload and abort request

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Dude, are you sure you want to leave? Think of the kittens!";
}
```

and if user confirm abort you save(content cache) and serve when user back to page.

Comment: I guess it doesn't prevent rails server from continuing handling request and the precess on server is going on.